# Ionic Cordova build Android error Transform Exception

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am getting a Ionic Cordova build Android error, see the image attached below.

- I updated Java with 1.8 JDK.
- I have removed and added platform.

But did not work.

[image]

Comment: What is your cordova version ?

Comment: cordova -version :  7.0.1

Comment: Based on the error message, I think two of the cordova plugins you have are using different versions of com.google.android.gms library version.

Run `cordova plugin ls` and paste the list of plugins.

Comment: Ankits-MacBook-Air:cys ankitmaheshwari$ cordova plugin ls
cordova-android-support-gradle-release 0.0.1 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 1.1.0 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.7 "Console"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.3.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 0.1.21 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"

Comment: SOME MORE : 
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3-dev "Whitelist"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 "Universal Links Plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem while deploying a project in ionic-cordova platforms android/ios

my terminal error image

they are just warnings... First remove the previous version of java development kit and reinstall it

```
$ cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

$ sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_101.jdk
```

Download the dmg from :

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Export your jdk to JAVA_home

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101/Contents/Home
```

if still error persists...then install the gradle in that folder....u having been working

```
$ brew install gradle
```

if gradle already installed then..

```
$ brew reinstall gradle
```

Check the android studio sdk and install the required tools
[android studio sdk]
my os is currently macosHighSierra..